# Why is All Might freaked out in the big villian fight scene?

Tags: my-hero-academia

I'm asking about the manga 
All Might learns from the villain who has stolen hundreds - thousands of quirks to become what he is that Izuku is somehow related to the previous All Might. Why is that so soul crushing to him?

Comment: I reread the manga chapter, It says that its Tomura Shigaraki is the grandson of the previous All Might, not Izuku. Says so in chapter 95. Did i miss something?

Comment: @Ryan I think they're related somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't it be? The bad guy just explained that he has robbed a ton of people from their quirks (quite possibly killing them in the process) and now when All Might himself is at his weakest, and Midoriya has still not mastered his gifted quirk, the danger is tremendous. Either of them or even both could be attacked and their quirk stolen, which would definitely be extremely bad.

Comment: all for one was captured and is imprisoned last i checked, he cant steal their quirk.

Comment: umm if you're talking about manga, then I'm afraid I've only seen the anime and that might not go as far as you know (or the OP asks about)

Comment: @Ryan you're right. All for one was TAUNTING him with this "secret" info. Even if true that they're related some way, why is it a problem?

Comment: the anime must have caught up to the manga then. He told all might about that relationship during their meeting, and that was only a few chapters ago.  Also, Wiki notes One for all can not be stolen due to how it works.

Comment: @Ryan so even if the powers can't be stolen, it still endangers Midori and that was the last thing he wanted

Comment: @JesseCohoon How is he in any more danger? The biggest and strongest villain was captured, and the villains are getting a lot weaker as time goes on as it stands.